# Adding a new line using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have a html snippet that looks like `*hi<br>*hello<br/>*test<br />`

I want this to be preformatted using javascript as

```
*hi<br>
*hello<br/>
*test<br />
```

Is there a regular expression and javascript to do this.

Comment: Err... why don't you read the documentation and find out for yourself? This is really basic stuff.

Comment: yes but I was having some problems. So, I just wanted to know the right way..thanks

Comment: Next time post the code you have so far.

Comment: So I have a comment....is the forum only for pros who know all things and know how to program a big app or is this for rookies also??
Since somebody downvoted and even matt pointed, can I get an idea of what to ask and what not to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str = str.replace(/<br>/g,"<br />\n");
```

This means replace all new lines `\n` with a `<br />`

Comment: Doesn't the OP want to *add* a new line after each BR element?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will help:

```
var str = '*hi<br>*hello<br/>*test<br />';
str.replace(new RegExp('<br\s*\\?>', 'i'), "$0\n");
```

That way you will keep diffrence between 
, 
 and 
.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use [replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) to replace * with *\n? You'd end up with an extra \n at the start but saves using regex.

Comment: yeah, but that is not desired in a bigger picture

Answer (score 0):

If str is your HTML string

```
str = str.replace(/\n/g , "<br />");
```

Comment: I wanted a new line in place of a break, not the other way round...thx